# How create a proxy for a class that is given as a parameter

Tags: java, generics, proxy

So I'm trying to create a Proxy for a class that is a parameter.

```
public static Object lookup(Class<?> cl,
                            CommunicationModule communicationModule) {
    InvocationHandler handler = new InvocationHandler() { ... };
    cl proxy = (cl) Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl.class.getClassLoader(),
                                           new Class[] { cl.class }, handler);
    return proxy;
}
```

But this doesn't work for some reason. What is wrong with this?

Comment: "cl cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cl` is a name of a parameter, not a type.

I guess the `.newProxyInstance()` method has a return type of `Proxy` (or `Object`), so you just need to do:

```
Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl.class.getClassLoader(),
                                     new Class[] { cl }, 
                                     handler);
```

Comment: Ok, this kind of answered my question. It worked when i did
    Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl.class.getClassLoader(),
                                     new Class[] { cl }, 
                                     handler);

Comment: That's possible, yes. As I told you, you needed to check the return type of the `newProxyInstance` method, which seems to be `Object`. :)